# List items internals (ImageView) randomly not showing

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have no idea why, but randomly the "arrow" doesn't show up on my list renderers/items (see pic). Does anybody know why? I'm not touching it with code. hierarchyviewer suggests the height is 1 when this happens. However even explicitly setting the height to 20dp it still happens. This also happens when I change the orientation of the phone. Disabling "convertView" and always creating a new one does not help. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" 
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    />

<com.domain.package.widgets.AnalogTextView
    style="@style/AnalogText"
    android:id="@+id/timeView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="11:30p - 7:00p"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    />

<TextView
    style="@style/LabelText"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/labelView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="WORK"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/labelView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    >
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sunday"
        android:text="Su"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Monday"
        android:text="M"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Tuesday"
        android:text="Tu"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Wednesday"
        android:text="W"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Thursday"
        android:text="Th"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Friday"
        android:text="F"
        />
    <TextView
        style="WeekDayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/Saturday"
        android:text="Sa"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/enabledView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's the overall layout of each row? RelativeLayout?

Comment: yes. It got cut off when I posted the code initially.

Comment: use traceview and see what is happening (if the view is there but hidden or something else)

Comment: like I said, "hierarchyviewer suggests the height is 1 when this happens"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a transparent color of 00000000 breaks imageviews from rendering in a listview. Changing it to 00FFFFFF fixes it!

Colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="themeColor">#FF8312</color>
<color name="primary_background">#C9C7C1</color>

<color name="primary_text_light">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="primary_text_dark">#4F4F4C</color>



<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
<!--     <color name="transparent">#00000000</color> -->

</resources>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="AlarmList" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
<!--        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item> -->
    <item name="android:divider">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/primary_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```